# How to open putty using batch and login then execute list of commands on bash

Tags: bash, batch-file, putty, sunos

I have a Sun OS server with oracle configured on it ; with database 11g i want to take backup , now am connecting to terminal using ssh on putty console but ,  what i need is finding a way to make it possible to connect using batch to ssh to the server then login then login to oracle then take the backup, is that possible and how.

Comment: Thank you. But what's happening here. Did you plan to do a tutorial?

Comment: sorry for that i was editing. :)

Comment: You can use [password-based](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.53b/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#3.7.3.8) or [passwordless](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.53b/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#3.7.3.14) login using plink/pscp.

Comment: I am not sure about logging in to oracle server. Never used it... But if it is possible via command line, it should be possible to automate it.

Comment: If someone could help me-- how is this a Linux server, if it has Solaris operating system on it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you really want to use putty to do this you can use the below in your command prompt in Windows(this will open the putty and its terminal and execute the passed argument in you text file):

```
putty.exe plink  -ssh -load profileName -l username -pw password -m commandPath -t
```

Or

```
putty.exe -ssh username@ip -pw password -m commandPath
```

e.g:

```
putty.exe -ssh rootz@10.10.10.10 -pw rootzpass -m c:\commands\mycommands.txt
```

Where *profileName* is the profile saved in putty and the *commandPath* is your local directory text file containing the commands you want to execute and the *username* is the server user and *ip* is the IP address for the server , the *password* is your server password then you can put whatever commands you want in your textFile.

**Reference**
[the.earth putty documentation](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/index.html)

Comment: For folks who are unable to make it work, check [this](https://superuser.com/a/1010093/740762) out

Comment: In my txt file with commands I have such text:
tail -f /tmp/spring.log;
/bin/sh
But if I press ctrl+c to stop showing logs and write some another command it close Putty window instead. Tell me please how to prevent this?

Comment: What - t mean at the end of first command line?

Comment: @sam Just looking myself, the -t command re enables ability to run commands manually / interact with the terminal, after the -m disables it.